# Is it possible to switch audio tracks in mkv file on Google Chromecast?

Tags: android, chromecast

I need to change audio track from Android.
As mentioned in the [official cast doc](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/media_tracks), I've tried to add the tracks using the following code:

```
MediaTrack audio1 = new MediaTrack.Builder(1, MediaTrack.TYPE_AUDIO)
  .setName("Audio 1")
  .setContentId(trackId)
  .setLanguage("en")
  .build();

MediaTrack audio2 = new MediaTrack.Builder(2, MediaTrack.TYPE_AUDIO)
  .setName("Audio 2")
  .setContentId(trackId2)
  .setLanguage("it")
  .build();

List tracks = new ArrayList();
tracks.add(audio1);
tracks.add(audio2);

MediaInfo mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Builder(url)
  .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
  .setContentType(getContentType())
  .setMetadata(getMetadata())
  .setMediaTracks(tracks)
  .build();
```

For `setContentId` I've retrieved tracks ids using ffmpeg and mediainfo, but it doesn't work.
I also tried to extract audio tracks and passed the url to audio file in `setContentId`, but it still not working.

For change the current track, I've tried using the `setActiveMediaTracks` method, but I've also tried changing the track from the CAF js code:

```
    playerManager.addEventListener(
  cast.framework.events.EventType.PLAYER_LOAD_COMPLETE, () => {
    const audioTracksManager = playerManager.getAudioTracksManager();

    // Get all audio tracks
    const tracks = audioTracksManager.getTracks();

    // Choose the first audio track to be active by specifying its ID
    audioTracksManager.setActiveById(tracks[0].trackId);
  });
```

Anyone have some idea?